# Как в Notepad++ выделить все нужные строки и переместить их выше?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Как в Notepad++ выделить все нужные строки и переместить их выше на 1 строку.
Выделяем все строки начинающиеся: #DESCRIPTION
Есть исходный файл:

```
#EXTM3U
http://strm.yandex.ru/kal/1hd/1hd0_169_480p.json/index-v1-a1.m3u8:1HD
#DESCRIPTION 1HD
http://rtmp.one.by:1300:1 муз HD
#DESCRIPTION 1 муз HD
http://rtmp.one.by:2300:Первый Музыкальный RU BY HD
#DESCRIPTION Первый Музыкальный RU BY HD
http://live.stranafm.cdnvideo.ru/stranafm/stranafm_hd.sdp/playlist.m3u8:Страна FM TV
#DESCRIPTION Страна FM TV
http://rtmp.one.by:1300:One.by HD
#DESCRIPTION One.by HD
http://stream.mediawork.cz/retrotv//retrotvHQ1/playlist.m3u8:Retro Music TV
#DESCRIPTION Retro Music TV
```

Все помеченные строки начинающиеся: #DESCRIPTION 
Нужно сместить на 1 строку вверх.

В результате должно быть так:

```
#EXTM3U
#DESCRIPTION 1HD
http://strm.yandex.ru/kal/1hd/1hd0_169_480p.json/index-v1-a1.m3u8:1HD
#DESCRIPTION 1 муз HD
http://rtmp.one.by:1300:1 муз HD
#DESCRIPTION Первый Музыкальный RU BY HD
http://rtmp.one.by:2300:Первый Музыкальный RU BY HD
#DESCRIPTION Страна FM TV
http://live.stranafm.cdnvideo.ru/stranafm/stranafm_hd.sdp/playlist.m3u8:Страна FM TV
#DESCRIPTION One.by HD
http://rtmp.one.by:1300:One.by HD
#DESCRIPTION Retro Music TV
http://stream.mediawork.cz/retrotv//retrotvHQ1/playlist.m3u8:Retro Music TV
```

Answer (score 1):

- Найти: **`(.*)\r\n(#DESCRIPTION.+)`**
- Заменить на: **`$2\r\n$1`**
- Режим поиска: *Регуляр. выражен.* ("и новые строки": *Откл.*)